# With PHP, how to check if decimal number is above or less than 50?

Tags: php, format, rounding, decimal, ceil

I am trying to check if a number which is inside a variable got a decimal number above 50 , or less than 50. Then depending on if it's 50 or higher, round the decimal number to 99 , and if it's less, round it to 00.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
return round( (ceil($price) - 0.01), 2);
}
```

It makes all decimal numbers round up to 99 . I would need only decimals which are 50 or higher to be rounded in 99, and 49 or less become 00.

How could I achieve this in PHP ? Many thanks, I'm stuck here and don't know much how to do that.

Comment: do you mean 0.99 or actually 99?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the off chance OP actually meant decimal places where 1.36 becomes 1.00 and 1.60 becomes 1.99.

Probably more elegant solutions, but here's one:

```
function roundPrice($price)
{
    $intVal = intval($price);
    if ($price - $intVal < .50) return (float)$intVal;
    return $intVal + 0.99;
}
```

http://codepad.org/5hIdQh4w

Answer (score 0):

> I would need only decimals which are 50 or higher to be rounded in **99**,
>   and 49 or less become **00**.

***Strange*** requirement but:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
  return $price >= 50 ? 99 : sprintf("%02s", 0);
}
```

For numbers greater than or equal to `50`, it would return `99` and for numbers less than `50`, it would return `00`

Comment: I'm thinking he means decimal places. Ex 1.37 becomes 1.00 and 1.67 becomes 1.99?

Comment: I think you missed a ? there... :)

Comment: Thanks guys. @tigrang: that is correct, sorry my question wasn't clear enough now that I read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really rounding, so just be direct about it.

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    if($price >= 50)
    {
        return 99;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Your stated problem does not handle the $price being equal to 50.  I made the assumption that the value of exactly 50 rounds up to 99.

Comment: `return 0;` would return just `0` not `00`

Comment: @Sarfraz - 0 is a number, not a string.  Do you want a string?

Comment: 0 <> 00?  Considering the statement of the problem, I'm assuming that 0 = 00.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: True but it seems OP wants two zeroes although they are same.

Comment: I can make it say `return 00`, but that won't make it behave any differently than it does.

Answer (score 0):

This modifies your function to return the decimal value if it's 50 or above and 0 otherwise.

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
   $decValue = round( (ceil($price) - 0.01), 2);

   if ($decValue >= 50) return $decValue;
   else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
public function roundPrice($price) {
    $p = round($price, 0);
    if( ceil($price) == $p) {
        return $p - 0.01;
    }
    return $p;
}
```

This returns X.99 for values >= X.5 and X.00 for all other values.